# Get a list of ALL services running and not and whether or not they should be running

Tags: macos, launchd, services, anti-virus

The basic problem I am trying to solve is that a Norton Anti-Virus process got stuck soaking up one full processor, and I had to kill it. (there was also a message on the norton app that said something like "Norton Anti virus can't continue, please reboot to continue protection") I don't want to reboot because I have lots of state (ssh tunnels, command history in a bunch of terminal sessions, etc) that is useful and will be lost on reboot.

I also don't want to be running around with broken anti-virus protection, so I had hoped `launchctl` would be able to give me a list of services that told me which ones were running, which ones were not running and which ones were configured to run as a daemon on start. Then upon finding a not running norton service that should be running I could simply restart it (or confirm that it had restarted itself).

Searching for answers on this is difficult because I get swamped by "list of running processes" results.

I've seen answers that talk about `launchctl bstree` and `launchctl bslist` which look close, but I'm on Sierra, and the man page for launchctl has this:

```
LEGACY SUBCOMMANDS
 Subcommands from the previous implementation of launchd are generally available, though some may be unimplemented. Unimplemented sub-
 commands are documented as such.
...
     bslist [PID | ..] [-j]
          This subcommand is not implemented and has been superseded by the print subcommand, which provides much richer information.
...
     bstree   This subcommand is not implemented and has been superseded by the print subcommand, which provides much richer information.
```

That's all well and good, but I can't see how the print command lists anything. It seems to require a specific service name, which hardly seems like a replacement for a "list" command. Is there a way to get a list out of print?

**Environment:** macOS Sierra

Comment: Install and launch  [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) - that's a GUI for launchctl which provides an overview/summary/error logs/error indicator as well as the possibility to enable/disable/start/stop/edit services broken down to system|user|single user / daemons|agents

Comment: I'd like a solution that doesn't require an additional application if possible. I'm trying to be somewhat selective about what I install on this machine.

Comment: LauchControl is definitely less intrusive than NortonAV (cough - no, I won't rant now, because I don't know your environment/restraints). But I'll try to find a solution for you without cat'ing plists and digging deeply into log files.

Comment: I said be selective, I did not say what the selection criteria was... yeah, I can possibly think of ways to write scripts to call a series of print commands, but I'm hoping there's a better option, especially since print specifically says not to rely on it's output in the man page.